# Select node for a Flink DataStream execution

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have been searching a lot but I didn't found a solution for this.

Lets supose some of the steps on the streaming process must be executed in just a subset of the available nodes/taskmanagers, while the rest of the tasks are free to be computed anywhere.

**¿How can I assign a DataStream to be executed ONLY in a node subset?**

This is required mainly for input/sink tasks as not every node in the cluster have the same conectivity / security restrictions.

I'm new on flink, so please forgive me if I'm asking for something obvious.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the thread [1]:  It is not completely possible to achieve this at "DataStream Level" but at "Job Level".

As explained by Vino Yang [1] in flink 1.6 over Yarn we can set up labels for jobs [2] and get some "allocability control" to our jobs, but it is possible for "low-level" tasks.

Thanks Vino for sharing his knowledge.

[1] http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201808.mbox/%3C1534090580.7952.107.camel@uam.es%3E

[2] https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7836